# How to retrieve multiple child categories from multiple parent categories in SQL database

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I'm currently retrieving the expense categories having multiple parent categories with their child categories and so on. For that i used common table expression in order to apply recursion but unable to retrieve the desired result.

This is the the result I'm getting

```
   CId                Tit                    Par
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 D61D6C22             Electricity Bill       NULL
 52113021             Wire Bill              D61D6C22
 E34B6F68             Wireless Bill          D61D6C22
 41A35796             B category Bill        52113021
 D063745A             A category Bill        52113021
```

This is the query I used:

```
WITH cte1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Id AS [CId], Title as [Tit], ParentId as [Par],
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Title)
    FROM 
        dbo.[ExpenseCategory] 
    WHERE
        ParentId IS NULL
    GROUP BY 
        Id, Title, ParentId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        Id AS [CId], Title, ParentId, RN
    FROM 
        cte1
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.[ExpenseCategory] ec ON cte1.[CId] = ec.ParentId
)
SELECT
    cte1.[CId], [Tit],[Par] 
FROM
    cte1   
ORDER BY
    RN ASC

   CId                Tit                    Par
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 D61D6C22             Electricity Bill       NULL
 52113021             Wire Bill              D61D6C22
 41A35796             B category Bill        52113021
 D063745A             A category Bill        52113021
 E34B6F68             Wireless Bill          D61D6C22
```

Comment: What's the result if you include the rownumber in the output?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the order by clause?

Comment: @johey Are you asking me to remove the Row_Number?

Comment: The result is the same i added in my question

Comment: I think the RN is not giving you what you expect. Add it to your output to make sure it generates what you want.

Comment: This article will probably help you: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21062.t-sql-hierarchical-table-sorting-with-a-parent-child-relation.aspx

Comment: The RN is generating the correct result. Its just that the as i have applied Parent id null so it is not finding the sub child category from the child category because the child categories are already having Parent id filled.

Comment: Thanks @johey. The given link completed solved my problem.